# How do I programmatically swap out a view control in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view, android-xml

I have the following XML layout driving my UI:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Username:" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        </EditText>

    </TableRow>

       <!-- more rows are here -->

</TableLayout>
```

I want to reuse this layout for another section of my app, but change something just slightly in one spot. I would like the `EditText` `txtUsername` to be changed to a `TextView`, in the same location and everything. So basically I am swapping out the EditText for a TextView in code.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is the only change you need I would do it by adding the TextView into your layout (defaulted to View.GONE) and using View.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) and View.setVisibility(View.GONE) where appropriate to swap them.

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Username:" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

    </EditText>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtUsernameTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" 
        android:visibility="gone">

    </TextView>
</TableRow>
```

Then in your java you can leave the activity you already have the same, in the new activity(where you want the TextView instead) do something like this:

```
editTextReference.setVisibility(View.GONE);
textViewReference.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

note that the two Views will need different values for their id.